# printf array string to sparql query php

Tags: php, sparql

I want to query SPARQL but with array. If that worked, I want to do iteration with all the array.

Using `sprintf` gives no result on sparql query:

```
$arrayName = array("Brassica_oleracea_var_italica","Brassica_oleracea_var_botrytis");
    $bmni = $sparql->query(sprintf('SELECT DISTINCT ?bmni WHERE {
                ?bmni kb:namaIlmiah kp:%s}', $arrayName[0]));
```

I have tried using `vprintf` but that gives me an error on `EasyRdf`:

> none
>   Fatal error: Uncaught EasyRdf_Exception: HTTP request for SPARQL query failed: 
>   Error 400: Parse error: 105 Encountered "  "105 "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting one of: "\ufeff" ... "base" ... "prefix" ... "select" ... "json" ... "describe" ... "construct" ... "ask" ... in C:...

Comment: [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data)?

Comment: shouldn't you use PHP string interpolation is intended? `$sparql->query("SELECT DISTINCT ?bmni WHERE {
                ?bmni kb:namaIlmiah kp:{$arrayName[0]}");` - does this not work?

Comment: @AKSW same error happen like using vprintf, I think EasyRdf cant handle array..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but I think `EasyRdf` cant return array, so
I transform my array into many variables. And it worked, it not efficient though.

I'm open to any suggestions to make this more efficient.

Thanks..

```
// array to variable
$var_name = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayName); $i++)
{
    $var_name = 'file' . $i;

    //looping every variable 
    $$var_name = $arrayName[$i];
    ${'file' . $i};
}

for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayName); $i++) { 
    $bmni = $sparql->query(sprintf('SELECT DISTINCT ?bmni WHERE {
                                        ?bmni kb:namaIlmiah kp:%s
                                    }', ${'file' . $i}));
}
```